# Jquery Ajax Json return - PHP notice / warning messes it up

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have an Ajax request that runs fine for the most part, it expects a json return and processes it accordingly. However if my PHP server throws an Notice (or warning or error for that matter), it triggers the ajax fail function automatically, EVEN if the response contains the Json array as part of it (usually after the PHP notice)

For development purposes, I don't want to turn of these PHP notices, I was wondering if the ajax could still handle the PHP notice and actually realize that the json return array was also included as part of the return, and somehow trigger the "done" function instead.

Not that it really matters but here a cut down version of the my ajax code, where having a PHP Notice being output by the server automatically triggers the "fail" callback, instead of "done" callback.

```
    function getTimeSlots() {
        $("#reservationtimebuttonsplaceholder").hide();

        $.post( "<?php echo Router::url(array('controller'=>'Bookings','action'=>'getMerchantAvailableTimeSlots_ajax')); ?>", $( ".reservationform" ).serialize(), function() {
            $(".reservationtimebuttons").empty();
        }, "json")

        .done(function(data) {

            var respstatus = data.status; 
            var message = data.message;
            var failtype = data.failtype;
            var timeslots = data.timeslots;

            if (respstatus === false) {
                $(".reservationtimebuttons").html(message)
            }

            if (respstatus === true) {
                $.each(timeslots, function (dataKey, dataVal) {                    
                    $.each(dataVal, function(timeKey,timeVal){
                        $.each(timeVal,function(timePropKey, timePropVal){
                            btn_id_postfix = timePropKey.replace(/\:/g,"");
                            $output = "<button id=\"btn" + btn_id_postfix + "\" class=\"btn btn-grey btn-timeselection\" value=\"" + timePropKey + "\" type=\"button\">" + timePropVal + "</button>";
                            $(".reservationtimebuttons").append($output);
                        });
                    });
                }); 
            }

        })

        .fail(function() {
            alert( "There was a problem getting the available timeslots! Please try again later" );
        })

        .always(function() {

        });
    }
```

Comment: Can't you handle this in the "always" function?

Comment: Yes, simply transform the error into not an error

Answer (score 0):

you can use simple ajax call , and not specify "json" as part of it , then this will get anything that comes from the php into the response of your ajax call.

and then try to JSON.parse it , if this function cannot parse the reponse to JSON , this means reponse is not properly formated and that means you php code has maybe some error or warning ,

then you can check if the response has something like status , so it is what you want with no error , and if not , php has shoot some errors beside your response .